Correct Formula Approach
Consider the following sample:

Big Picture
I need to subtract 2 Weeks from all dates in column B, only when the Time in Column D matches a particular time(in this example 9PM), regardless of category type in Column C. Ignore Column E, as this is a calculated column (F - D)
Issue
I'm having trouble picturing how I'm going to flag Row 6 and Row 11, if I group by Dates (B2 and B15). Am I mistaken in thinking that each row needs a date for the INDEX/MATCH to work?

I've found the following formula help, but any help or another formula type would be appreciated. I might be overthinking it:

Subtracting Weeks From a Date - Easy Part
Index Match Between Times - Not So Easy. Note that I only want the time to match not fall between. I was also thinking of VLOOKUP if match doesn't work, but again, do I need a date on every row?


Please check the formula is helpful：
=IF(D2="9PM",LOOKUP(1,0/(B$2:B2<>""),B$2:B2)-14,LOOKUP(1,0/(B$2:B2<>""),B$2:B2))

Only when the Time in Column D is "9PM", 2 Weeks will be subtracted from dates in column B.

This Worked Perfect after changing Cell References to not match the sample and Changing the False Condition to the standard "".  I only needed dates on rows where TIME(21,0,0) is True

This might be another question but is there any way to divide a group of Cells into an Array?  I only need the 9PMs when the Items in Category 1 =<some string>.
